# I installed 10.04 on my laptop, and the internet is gone

Tags: 10.04, installation, internet-connection

So I just installed 10.04 onto my Toshiba L745D-S4220 laptop. I installed it with a wired connection and it installed fine, but noticibly never asked for any internet connection settings when I installed. So I restart, and there is no connection, even though it is plugged into ethernet and I know that there are many strong wifis around the area. 
I tried ifconfig -a, it sees the ethernet connection. I tried iwconfig and it says that there are no connections available. It seems that there are no drivers that installed for connecting up to any sort of internet. Help!

Comment: Please look at this Q&A and add to your question some of the suggested hardware details and logs so that we can help you with your issue.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 1):

## Ubuntu 10.04

From [LaunchPad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/132667)

The simplest way to get it working is here :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lexical/hwe-wireless
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192ce-dkms
```

The other option would be to upgrade to 11.10 (Oneiric)

This is because the necessary drive is included in the Oneiric (3.0.0) kernel.

See this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/795770)

Comment: You'll be able to add comments I think when you've earned 50+ rep - you are half-way there - just need three more upvotes... just lookout for questions that have enough information that you can give a definitive answer to.

Comment: yeah sure. pastebinned

http://pastebin.com/nJTBckTR

Comment: Thank you , with that information I think you have a few options.